# jtable-jquery sorting and linq to sql

Tags: c#, jquery, linq, jquery-jtable

**Edit/Solution**
What I did, I don't think it is elegant, was two folds:
1. Use an inline sql query to order the dataset.
2. Use Linq to add the starting index (skip) and number of dataset to display (take).

```
var testDetail = db.Database.SqlQuery<GroupMemberDTVM>("SELECT FirstName, LastName, GroupMemberEmail FROM GroupMember WHERE GroupCode = @p0 ORDER BY " + jtSorting + "", _sid);

var testOutput = (from c in testDetail
                  select c).Skip(jtStartIndex).Take(jtPageSize);
```

Using jtable (jquery), the sorting parameter is a string.  How do one integrate the parameter to Linq?
The parameter "LastName ASC".  How to convert that to g.LastName ASC?  Thanks!

```
IEnumerable<GroupMemberDTVM> groupMembers = 
(from g in db.groupMember
 where g.GroupCode == _sid
 orderby ?????
 select new GroupMemberDTVM
 {
  FirstName = g.FirstName,
  LastName = g.LastName,
  GroupMemberEmail = g.GroupMemberEmail
}).Distinct().Skip(jtStartIndex).Take(jtPageSize).AsEnumerable();
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend method syntax, as it's more flexible and (imo) easier to read. Other improvements, use the var keyword, and you don't need the `AsEnumerable` Try this:

```
var groupMembers = db.groupMember
    .Where(g => g.GroupCode == _sid)
    .OrderBy(g => g.LastName)
    .Select(g => new GroupMemberDTVM(){
        FirstName = g.FirstName,
        LastName = g.LastName,
        GroupMemberEmail = g.GroupMemberEmail,
    })
    .Distinct()
    .Skip(jtStartIndex)
    .Take(jtPageSize);
```

Also, I'm not really familiar with query syntax but i think all you need is to say `g.LastName` where your ????s are

Comment: I understood that the format ought to be as per your answer, and my question was how to replace the ??? which is a string (eg. "LastName ASC" to g.LastName.